# How to use Azure Cognitive Search to connect Meta and Raw data?

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

we want to store our measurement data in an Azure Datalake. The dataset consists of the raw data and the metadata. These two datasets are in different files. For the search we want to use Cognitive Search.

How do you link the metadata with the raw data in Coginitve Search, so that in the search results (which are based on the metadata) the associated raw data is also linked.

Thanks.

Many greetings
Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the same index for both datasets.  If your raw data contains dataID, colA, colB, and colC, and your metadata contains dataID, colD, and colE, you can create an index that encompasses both: dataID, colA, colB, colC, colD, and colE.

To get the data into your index, one option is an indexer.  You can easily set one up in the Azure portal by going to your Cognitive Search resource and clicking the "Import Data" button.  Specify "ADLS Gen 2" (Azure Datalake storage) as the data source and the index you've created as the index to pull into.

You can create two different indexers, one for your raw data and one for your metadata, that map the various fields correctly, but both can write to the same index.  (An indexer always contains a data source from where it pulls data and an index to which it pushes data, so with two indexers, you could have two separate data sources for raw data vs. metadata and the same index for both.)  Finally, querying that one index will give you joint search results containing both the metadata and raw data.

Some links that might be helpful:

- [How to create indexers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-create-indexers)
- [Create index - REST reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/create-index)
- [Create indexer - REST reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/rest/api/searchservice/create-indexer)